# How to uncheck on load and toggle check in two checkbox angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I want to uncheck the two checkbox on startup, and allow user to select only one check box at a time. Can I do it only using from **ng-...** attribute?

I am trying the following code

```
            <div style="border:1px solid">
                <label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="!Titleshine_check" ng-model="blink_check">Blink</label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;(OR)&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="!blink_check" ng-model="Titleshine_check">Shine</label>
                <br>
            </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2BLssmNTB5r8LjeGZf65?p=preview

Comment: You should use RADIO instead of CHECKBOX

Comment: How can I access the radio button value?

Comment: below you got full example on your code posted from your plunker with viewing value you chosen in span

Answer (score 0):

Here you got full example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

                        <div style="border:1px solid">

                        select type:
                        <form>
                          <input type="radio" name="opt1" ng-change="radioValue" ng-model="radioValue" value="this" unchecked> this
                          <br>
                          <input type="radio" name="opt2" ng-change="radioValue" ng-model="radioValue" value="that" unchecked> that
                        </form>
                        <span ng-bind="radioValue"></span>

                    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

and js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.radioValue="empty";
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really, really want the checkboxes you can do it like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ukDKjBZsp7AtY5UiIhBj?p=preview

```
<div style="border:1px solid">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="blink_check">Blink</label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;(OR)&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-click="blink_check = !blink_check" ng-model="!blink_check" >Shine</label>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Working with checkboxes in this way may result with some problems on some browsers. You should use native functions as far it is possible, it will leave your app less heavy and better to read code and understand it.

Comment: @mark  Some time both will disabled, but in your answer. should enable one check box at least